# How do I add "bytes" to this memory address? ARM V6 Assembly Code

Tags: assembly, binary, arm

I'm currently doing a microcontroller module in Engineering. I don't understand this question.

*"Assuming that SP is 0x0000_2220 initially, what is its value after executing the instruction PUSH {r0,r2}?"*

SP - Stack Pointer

PUSH - Instruction

R0, R2 - Registers

From what I've read I need to decrease the stack pointer by 8 bytes, *Resources attached*. I can convert that hex address to binary but how do I subtract 8 bytes when I don't know what number that represents? Guess my question is more of a number representation question now that I think about it :)

[Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydcch.png)

Comment: Don't convert it to binary, just use a hex calculator to subtract 8.  Or convert it to decimal and subtract 8 if you prefer, then convert that back to hex.  We generally avoid binary for doing arithmetic even though that's the processors approach.

Comment: Math works the same regardless of what system you use to represent numbers.  Subtraction in all place-value systems including hex works like it does in decimal.  (But remember `0x20 - 8` = `0x18` because 8 is half of 16, just like 20-5 = 15 because 5 is half of 10.

Comment: Or in other words, `0x0 - 0x8` is `0x8` with a borrow of 1 from the next hex digit to the left.  If you're going to do a lot of this sort of thing, then mental arithmetic in hex might be a good skill to practice.